# How to rewrite a Path in asp routing?

Tags: asp.net, .net, routes

I am using routing in my asp project and was wondring if it was possible to rewrite the url if a user makes a request to .aspx page ?
I have configured a route as

```
route.MapPageRoute("Welcome", "welcome", "~/Welcome.aspx");
```

now if a user makes a request for Welcome.aspx i want to rewrite the url as /welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls nuget package.

It will give routing to all pages rewriting the url without the .aspx extension.

No need to write custom routing for all pages individually.